# Importing Angular Material Themes

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-6

I am building a new component and would like to use Angular Material themes. I imported the themes from Angular Material repository but the mixins are not getting applies to the control. If I add any style in the the stylesheet it gets applied but the mixing are not applied to the controls. Can you please let me know what I might be missing here. This is what I have implemented:

a) Created a custom control in the project
b) used the theme.scss file from Angular Material and imported it in the component.scss

Answer (score 0):

You have to

1. rename your `styles.css` to `styles.scss`
2. put the import of the `theme.scss` into your `styles.scss`
3. adjust the entry in your `angluar.json` from `styles.css` to `styles.scss`

then run `ng serve`

Comment: I'd like to hear where this got the OP. this looks good to me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a built-in theme, then you need to [add your chosen CSS file to the styles array of your project's angular.json file](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#using-a-pre-built-theme).